# How to get data out of a deferred callback;

Tags: jquery

How do I get the returned data to work outside the deferred callback below?

```
             results.done(function(data)
             {
                   alert(data); // works
             });

             alert(data); // does not work but need it to work...
```

Comment: you can't, without a settimeout. simple as that. there's no reason to.

Comment: Whatever is written after the callback executes sooner than the callback. You can't send data back in time.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: Wow, you mean I'm stuck to add all my code that is dependent on this data inside this deferred callback function....

Answer (score 4):

This will work, sometimes, **but is a very bad idea.**

```
var badIdea;
results.done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
    badIdea = data;
});

setTimeout(function(){
    alert(badIdea);
},10000);
```

Re-think your logic and do not try to get data outside of the done callback.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to store the data in a location accessible from the outer scope. If you store it in a global variable from inside the callback, it would be available; you just need to make sure, then, that the outer code is only executed after the asynchronous code completes.

Alternatively, you are able to call "done" multiple times (.done() returns the deferred object, so .done().done() or temp = .done(); temp.done() would work). If the result has already completed previously, the callback will execute immediately.

Comment: I was excited to learn and use deferred but didn't account code inside the callback function to be stuck... Do you have an example?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "stuck"? What are you looking for an example of?